# Making multiple read attempts on a TCP socket vs. a single read with longer timeout

Tags: java, sockets, networking, tcp

I'm reviewing some inherited code from a TCP client (written in Java) which submits a request to a server via a TCP socket and then reads the response with a timeout. If the timeout is triggered, it will retry the read up to a maximum number of attempts.

My question is, is there any operational difference between making ***n*** read attempts with timeout ***T*** vs. making a single read attempt with timeout ***n*** x ***T***?

Here's the basic loop in Java-esque pseudo code

```
Socket s = new Socket(myHost, myPort);
socket.setSoTimeout(READ_TIMEOUT);

out.println(myRequest);  // Assume out is a PrintWriter

while (true) {

    try {
        response = in.readLine(); // Assume in is a BufferedReader
        break;
    } catch (SocketTimeoutException stx) {
        failedReads++;
    }

    if (failedReads == MAX_FAILED_READS) {
        break;
    }
}

// Got the response or reached max attempts
```

Comment: Either way, you'll be waiting on a single piece of data of a specific type. If you want to commit a thread to it, without any potential actions in-between, I don't see why a single read with `n * T` timeout would be an issue. Seems protocol-specific, but good question.

Comment: Depending on how the reading is implemented in detail, I'd assume there is a slight possibility that the timeout exception may be raised while a partial response has already been read. A retry attempt after a partial read could then result in a broken response received. A single read with a longer timeout would eliminate that possibility.

Comment: @Durandal I've actually come across that, the real logic actually appends the result of each read onto the response rather than assuming it will all successfully read in one go.